# MySQL bigdump.php data not saving

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using `bigdump.php` to import few million lines into my Database. For now, I'm testing the speed of import by importing only 550k lines.

For some reason, if `autocommit` is set `0` the data will not save in the table. What makes this interesting is that couple hours ago, the exact same setup worked just fine.

After I cleaned the database and make a new one, this started to happen.

Can someone enlight me a bit what's going on?

I'm importing the data from CSV file if this does make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL docs:

> If a session that has autocommit disabled ends without explicitly committing the final transaction, MySQL rolls back that transaction.

I simply put:

```
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

After `bigdump.php` is finished. The reason why this worked earlier with the same setup is still a mystery.